# What is $pdf in script and how to use page_text function to add text inside page dompdf?

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm a new user with dompdf, i'm trying to make pagination and add custom html to specific page number. I see in some posts they have $pdf, PAGE_NUM,PAGE_COUNT... but I dont know how to use them.
Here is what I did:

PdfController.php

```
<?php
$html = view('pdf')->render();
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->load_html($html);

$canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
$cpdf = $canvas->get_cpdf();

$font = $dompdf->getFontMetrics()->get_font("helvetica", "bold");

$firstPageId = $cpdf->getFirstPageId();
$objects = $cpdf->objects;
$pages = array_filter($objects, function($v) {
    return $v['t'] == 'page';
});
$number = 1;
foreach($pages as $pageId => $page) {
    if(($pageId + 1) !== $firstPageId) {
        $canvas->reopen_object($pageId + 1);
        $canvas->text(72, 18, "<div>Header: $number</div>", $font, 6, array(0,0,0));
        $canvas->close_object();
        $number++;
    }
}

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", ["Attachment" => false]);
exit(0);
?>
```

And here is html:

```
<style>
    body {
      counter-reset: page;
    }

    .footer:not(:first-child) .page-number:before {
      counter-increment: page;
      color: red;
      content: 'Page ';
    }

    .footer:not(:first-child) .page-number:after {
      color: red;
      content: counter(page);
    }
</style>

<script type="text/php">
    if ( isset($pdf) ) {
        $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
        if (PAGE_NUM===2) $pdf->page_text(72, 18, "<div>Header: {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}</div>",
                        $font, 6, array(0,0,0));
    }
</script>

<div class="footer fixed-section">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="report-time">08/05/2016 09:43:06</span><br>
    <span class="promo">Generated by ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="signature-warning">This is page 0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="page-number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="footer fixed-section">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="report-time">08/05/2016 09:43:06</span><br>
    <span class="promo">Generated by ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="signature-warning">This is page 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="page-number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="footer fixed-section">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="report-time">08/05/2016 09:43:06</span><br>
    <span class="promo">Generated by ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="signature-warning">This is page 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="page-number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="footer fixed-section">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="report-time">08/05/2016 09:43:06</span><br>
    <span class="promo">Generated by ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="signature-warning">This is page 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="page-number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="footer fixed-section">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="report-time">08/05/2016 09:43:06</span><br>
    <span class="promo">Generated by ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="signature-warning">This is page 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="page-number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="footer fixed-section">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="report-time">08/05/2016 09:43:06</span><br>
    <span class="promo">Generated by ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="signature-warning">This is page 5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="page-number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="footer fixed-section">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="report-time">08/05/2016 09:43:06</span><br>
    <span class="promo">Generated by ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="signature-warning">This is page 6</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="page-number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="footer fixed-section">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="report-time">08/05/2016 09:43:06</span><br>
    <span class="promo">Generated by ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="signature-warning">This is page 7</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="page-number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="footer fixed-section">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="report-time">08/05/2016 09:43:06</span><br>
    <span class="promo">Generated by ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="signature-warning">This is page 8</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="page-number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="footer fixed-section">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="report-time">08/05/2016 09:43:06</span><br>
    <span class="promo">Generated by ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="signature-warning">This is page 9</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="page-number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="footer fixed-section">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="report-time">08/05/2016 09:43:06</span><br>
    <span class="promo">Generated by ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="signature-warning">This is page 10</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="page-number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="footer fixed-section">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="report-time">08/05/2016 09:43:06</span><br>
    <span class="promo">Generated by ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="signature-warning">This is page 11</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="page-number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="footer fixed-section">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="report-time">08/05/2016 09:43:06</span><br>
    <span class="promo">Generated by ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="signature-warning">This is page 12</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="page-number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="footer fixed-section">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="report-time">08/05/2016 09:43:06</span><br>
    <span class="promo">Generated by ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="signature-warning">This is page 13</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="page-number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="footer fixed-section">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="report-time">08/05/2016 09:43:06</span><br>
    <span class="promo">Generated by ...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span class="signature-warning">This is page 14</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="page-number"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my question **What is $pdf in script and how to use page_text function to add text inside page dompdf? Or how to do the same in php will better?**

Comment: You'd have to look at those scripts, find where $pdf is defined, and then you'll know what it represents. In what you've shown us, it doesn't appear to be defined, so I assume you've provided us with an incomplete sample

Comment: @ADyson sorry, the sample provide me show me as above. Its easy if i have full example.

Comment: I guess the sample provider made a mistake then. I don't know this library, but I'd guess it's meant to be an instance of `$dompdf` instead. Also `<script type="text/php">` looks wrong...pretty sure you can't open a PHP block like that, you'd need to use `<?php`. I wonder if that snippet is actually just supposed to be shown on screen as part of the tutorial? Hard to know without reference to the original source.

Comment: @ADyson no, this sample is right but it's hard to find full sample. I guess this $pdf pass from controller but page_text does not working.

Comment: Is there no controller code provided for creating the HTML page? All you've shown is code which generates the PDF, not the HTML.

Comment: @ADyson you are so funny, this library convert html to pdf. This load html from file by $dompdf->load_html($html), it can parse php in html and excute them but I can not use some functions or variables avaible.

Comment: Why am I funny? You're asking about some PHP code embedded withn the HTML. So if you want to execute that PHP code then you'll need to know the code which came just before it. Remember I don't know DOMPDF specifically, but I'm doing my best to help you based on limited knowledge of where this code came from and what you think it's going to do. If you prefer, I can forget about it.

Comment: you can take a look dompdf api https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#dompdf-api

Comment: Well `page_text` is a function of dompdf's canvas, so maybe... `$pdf = $dompdf->get_canvas(); $pdf->page_text...`, as per the example in those instructions??

Comment: I see in their example that $canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas(); can draw text (their example does not work too)  and $pdf come from it but dont know where $canvas can pass

Comment: I attempted to answer your question as best as I could, but if you're able to provide more guidance on what you want your output to look like we can provide more guidance on how to get there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot going on here, but I'll do my best to answer. I'm assuming your using the current release.

First, the Canvas object. This provides direct access to the underlying PDF writer back end. As such you can't use it to render HTML. Any styling on the text has to be made manually. So writing out HTML into the PDF like you're attempting to do with the DIV element won't work. Just write out the text you want.

Second, the $pdf variable. This variable is an eval-local variable you can use within your page scripts and holds a reference to the Canvas object. You don't need to do anything to access it, just reference it within any Canvas scripts.

In your containing file (e.g. PdfController.php):

```
$canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
$canvas->page_script(<<<EOF
  if ($PAGE_NUM !== 1) {
    $font = $fontMetrics->get_font("helvetica", "bold");
    $pdf->text(72, 18, "Header: $PAGE_NUM of $PAGE_COUNT", $font, 6, array(0,0,0));
  }
EOF;
);
```

Note that you don't need to parse through the PDF objects to find the page you want. Page scripts are run on each page after the HTML has been fully rendered so all you have to do is check the current page.

In your actual HTML document:

```
<script>
if ( !isset($pdf) ) { return; }
$pdf->page_script(<<<EOF
  if ($PAGE_NUM !== 1) {
    $font = $fontMetrics->get_font("helvetica", "bold");
    $pdf->text(72, 18, "Header: $PAGE_NUM of $PAGE_COUNT", $font, 6, array(0,0,0));
  }
EOF;
);
</script>
```

Note that in order to use HTML-embedded script you have to enable it. This is a security option since HTML-embedded script could be used as a vector to exploit your system if you allow unsanitized user content.

To enable HTML-embedded script:

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf(['isPhpEnabled' => true]);
```

Third, about `page_script` and `page_text`. These Canvas methods are executed in the context of each page of the PDF document after the HTML has been fully rendered. This is different from other methods, such as `text`, which are executed only on the active PDF page.

Currently, because of the way Dompdf renders documents the total number of pages ($PAGE_COUNT) only accurately reflects the number of pages after the HTML document has been fully rendered. As such to write out that value to the PDF you have to use either page_text or page_script.

---

FYI, though you don't generally mix Canvas script and HTML it is possible to do so in a limited way. Here's a recent discussion on the topic: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/discussions/2475

Comment: isPhpEnabled is right, thank you so much